# Sensing a USB charger state via an Arduino powered via a separate USB charger

Tags: arduino, usb, mains, opto-isolator

I want to sense the state of a 240 outlet. I have an [adapter plug](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09ZP6WGMD) that I believe will allow me to use a standard USB charger (rated 120/240 V) to provide 5 V when the outlet is powered.

I also plan on powering an Arduino module using a separate USB charger.

Since neither USB charger actually has a ground, I don't think there is any common reference between the 5 V signal I want to sense and the 5 V supply used by the Arduino, I feel the right solution is to use an optocoupler.

The 5 V signal I want to sense would drive the photodiode input to the coupler, and the collector of the output would be driven from the Arduino 5 V supply.

Am I missing anything here?
Either with the adapter plug, which I think changes the form factor of the plug, i.e. 240 V now comes out on what looks like a 120 V plug, or with the need for the optocoupler?

Obviously I would need a correctly sized resistor both in the input diode circuit and as the open-collector pull-up.  Then when the outlet is off, the collector will be at the Arduino's VDD, and when on the collector will be at or near the Arduino's VSS.

Comment: Are you wanting to find out when the socket has power?  Or do you have something plugged into it and you want to know if that is on?

Comment: The USB power supply will be isolated, so you can put the Arduino ground to its negative and a GPIO pin to it's +5V.  I don't think the optoisolator is necessary here.

Comment: @jonathanjo I want to find out when the outlet is on.  It's on when my deep well pump is receiving power and that's what I really want to know.

Comment: My suggestion would be a photodiode glued to some kind of indicator lamp.  Volt-free, easy to do and test, and you might be able to find a more-directly-connected LED on the motor or whatever.

Comment: @user1850479 They are both isolated so I am thinking the "ground" on each could be at different voltages.

Comment: @jonathanjo I want to log when the outlet is on (and hence the pump) to a database which is why I need the signal compatible with the Arduino microcontroller.

Comment: Indeed: you can use phototransistor inputs very easily with Arduinos, see for example [this](https://learn.parallax.com/tutorials/robot/shield-bot/robotics-board-education-shield-arduino/chapter-6-light-sensitive-14) or any search for `arduino phototransistor`

Comment: Since they are isolated you can make them be the same voltage by connecting them.  That is the point of an isolated power supply.  I don't see the purpose of adding a second isolator in series with the one in the power supply?

Comment: @user1850479 I guess I have been doing this all along in the past, tying the negative side of 2 wire sensors to the ground pin of the Arduino.  I guess in those cases both were powered from a 120V outlet,  and in this case one will be powered from a 120V outlet and the other from a 240V outlet, so somehow I felt that would not work.

Comment: use a linear DC power adapter instead of a  switchingUSB charger ... a doorbell transformer would also work

Answer (score 1):

There is no common reference between two 5V USB supplies, unless you connect them together.

So there is no need for any optocoupler between the two.